# Estimation of $\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^4}dx$

Tags: integration, estimation

> Prove that $\dfrac34<\displaystyle\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^4}\,\mathrm dx<\dfrac {9}{10}$.

My working:

We can easily prove that
$$\begin{align}
\frac{1}{1+x^2}&<\frac{1}{1+x^4}<1-x^4+x^8,\forall x\in (0,1) \\
\implies\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^2}\,\mathrm dx&<\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^4}\,\mathrm dx<\int_0^1(1-x^4+x^8)\,\mathrm dx \\
\implies\frac34&<\frac{\pi}{4}<\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^4}\,\mathrm dx<(1-\frac 15+\frac 19)=\frac{41}{45}
\end{align}$$

But unfortunately $\dfrac {9}{10}<\dfrac{41}{45}$.

Comment: Do the same with $1-x^4+x^8-x^{12}+x^{16}$ instead of  $1-x^4+x^8$...

Comment: Ohh I got it $\frac {1}{1+x^4}<1-\frac{x^4}{2}\implies \int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^4}dx<\frac{9}{10}$

Comment: If you have solved your own problem, It is OK to write it as an answer and mark it as accepted. That way, this question will be complete.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can easily prove that
$$\begin{align}
1-x^3&<\frac{1}{1+x^4}<1-\frac{x^4}{2},\forall x\in (0,1) \\
\implies\int_0^1 1-x^3\,\mathrm dx&<\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^4}\,\mathrm dx<\int_0^11-\frac{x^4}{2}\,\mathrm dx \\
\implies\frac34&<\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+x^4}\,\mathrm dx<1-\frac {1}{10}=\frac{9}{10}
\end{align}$$